# Java starting services with "special" name

Tags: java

I want to start these 2 services:

```
String s7 = "OracleDBConsoleorcl";
String s8 = "Oracle ORCL VSS Write Service";
```

Using this method:

```
private void startService(String SERVICE_NAME) {
    String[] script = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "sc", "start", SERVICE_NAME};//to start service

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.equals("0")) {
                System.out.println(line);
            } else {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
}
```

This is the problem: s7 gets started properly but s8 doesnt because (my guess) is that the service name contains spaces, leading to this error:

```
[SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 1060:
The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

I mean, the service is existing here:

[image: oracleProblem]

Anything i could try? I did try String s8 = "\"Oracle ORCL VSS Write Service\""; to give cmd the right format but neither works...

Comment: Does it work if you quote it? String s8 = "\"Oracle ORCL VSS Write Service\"";

Comment: Try it without the "cmd /c" - `sc` is a `.exe` rather than a cmd internal so Java can execute it directly without using cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displayed string is not the real/internal service name.

Open the properties of that entry in the services list and you can see its service name (which does not contain spaces).